# Apply gradient effect at border level of a div

Tags: css

I am trying to give gradient effect to a div at the border level with two colors inset using css. But i am unable to get the same as shown in example.The gradient effect should be from top to middle of sqaure area.
I do have marked the area of gradient effect in image.

[image]

Comment: what you tried code ?

Comment: tried with this but didnt get.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Gorfi/pen/wFsmj

Comment: Please post your code in the question: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: With a quick google search I found several answers. Have you tried any of those? https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: @sumitpatel, don't make edits that break the rules - codepen links must be accompanied by code in the question - just highlighting a random word as code is not sufficient

Comment: can we apply border with gradient effect for rounded buttons

Comment: actually i do need gradient effects at the border level not the entire button but it should be rounded.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jdeepak91/Lnu0ubaf/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```css
.box {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 10px solid #3e3ad5;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #d53a3a;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 10px 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 10px 100%;
    background-size: 10px 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3ad5 0%, #d53a3a 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3ad5 0%, #d53a3a 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -o-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3ad5 0%, #d53a3a 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3ad5 0%, #d53a3a 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>Border Gradient</span></div>
```

Comment: its fine for div buddy but when it comes to button it doesn't apply

Comment: i do want to apply this to a button at the border level.